# can a div's text be made invisible but its background image remains visible

Tags: css

I would like to make the text content of my div invisible but still display the background image. Is that possible?

In the app, the div's single-character content determines which class is conditionally applied to the div, but the content itself is not what needs to be displayed. I want to display the image associated with the class.

Comment: `color: transparent;`? is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/5vCfB/) what you want? The `div` has text but text color is transparent.

Comment: try with div(or p or span or ...) inside div.. amd make one invisible.. or give z-index such that background come before the text...

Comment: @Harry, yes indeed.  If you make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `color:transparent;` to the `div` CSS. It would make the `div` have text but text color is transparent with respect to the background.

**CSS (with sample image):**

```
#test{
    background-image: url('http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/12f0cc69cd9742faa9c8ee0f7b0d210e.jpg');
    height: 300px;
    color: transparent;
}
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/5vCfB/).